# Enable/Disable options in a related dropdown without triggering all dropdowns with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all, thank you to everyone who has helped me progress, learn, and teach myself by example on Stackoverflow. That aside, I recently posted concerning a demo found at http://beta.acinonyxsim.com/demo. I am back with another question that didn't quite fit in with my previous one:

When adding base markings, certain markings are only limited to Tan/White. At this time, I am listing all available colors when you first click add a base marking, then disabling and re-enabling as needed. This seems to work, but on change it takes the value and places it in all .base_marking_color classed dropdowns. My code is below:

```
$('div#base_markings').on('change', 'select.base_marking', function(){
    $('select.base_marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $('select.base_marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]:not([value=""])').prop('disabled', false);
    var base_marking = $.trim($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    var base_marking_color = $(this).closest('div.base_marking_options').find('select.base_marking_color').val();
        if (base_marking == 'Back Leg' || base_marking == 'Blanket' || base_marking == 'Cape' || base_marking == 'Cloak' || base_marking == 'Cloak 2' || base_marking == 'Coat' || base_marking == 'Dorsal' || base_marking == 'Edging' || base_marking == 'Forehead' || base_marking == 'Front' || base_marking == 'Inners' || base_marking == 'Legs' || base_marking == 'Limbs' || base_marking == 'Lower Belly' || base_marking == 'Mask' || base_marking == 'Nooks' || base_marking == 'Parts' || base_marking == 'Paws' || base_marking == 'Royal   (Wild Only)' || base_marking == 'Sable 1' || base_marking == 'Sable 2' || base_marking == 'Saddle' || base_marking == 'Shoulder' || base_marking == 'Smudge' || base_marking == 'Spots' || base_marking == 'Swabs' || base_marking == 'Tail' || base_marking == 'Top' || base_marking == 'Trim' || base_marking == 'Under Flank   (Wild Only)' || base_marking == 'Upper Belly') {
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="7"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="8"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="6"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
        if (base_marking_color == '' || base_marking_color == 6 || base_marking_color == 1) {
            $('select.base_marking_color').val('5');
        }
        else {
            $('select.base_marking_color').val(base_marking_color);
        }
    }
    else if (base_marking == 'Bottom' || base_marking == 'Chest' || base_marking == 'Collar' || base_marking == 'Tail End' || base_marking == 'Tail Tip' || base_marking == 'Tips' || base_marking == 'Toes' || base_marking == 'Unders 1' || base_marking == 'Unders 2' || base_marking == 'Unders 3' || base_marking == 'Unders 4' || base_marking == 'Unders 5' || base_marking == 'Unders 6' || base_marking == 'Unders 7' || base_marking == 'Unders 8   (Wild Only)') {
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="5"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="4"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="7"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="8"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="6"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select.base_marking_color option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
        if (base_marking_color == '' || base_marking_color != 6 && base_marking_color != 1) {
            $('select.base_marking_color').val('6');
        }
        else {
            $('select.base_marking_color').val(base_marking_color);
        }
    }
    processDemo();
});
```

I apologize for any formatting errors, being blind makes it difficult to format things correctly.

In summary, this code *should* do the following:

- Disable and re--enable the necessary colors when a base marking changes
- Maintain the user's selection if they are changing between markings with the same color set (example: white/tan for bottom, chest, unders, etc.)

Thank you so much for any help given.

Comment: **sidenote:** Instead of that incredibly long base_marking if-clause, it might be more efficient (certainly more readable) if you first create an array with all the values (`var base_markings = ['Back Leg', 'Blanket', 'Cape', et cetera];`) and then check if the base_marking is in that array (`if (base_markings.indexOf(base_marking) != -1) {...}`). NOT supported in <IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you set the value, your jQuery selector is a class, so all elements with that class get the value:

```
$('select.base_marking_color').val(base_marking_color);
```

Instead, you should only select the current element.
Luckily, you already do that in the line just before that incredibly long base_marking if-clause:

```
var base_marking_color = $(this).closest('div.base_marking_options').find('select.base_marking_color').val();
```

**1. Just change that line to these two lines:**

```
var base_marking_option = $(this).closest('div.base_marking_options').find('select.base_marking_color')[0];
var base_marking_color = $(base_marking_option).val();
```

- The `[0]` at the end is needed to select the actual DOM element that's inside the jQuery-object.

**2. And now change the line where you set the value, to this:**

```
$(base_marking_option).val(base_marking_color);
```

*(There are three other lines where you set the value, obviously change those too.)*